# Looking fo a Hummer H2 SFX Pack

Tags: sfx, car, sound-library, custom

So I am looking for a SFX pack/library specifically of a Hummer H2. If I could get access to the actual car (especially the one from the film but it was shot international) I would record it myself. Finding one (without renting one for the day...über expensive) has proven difficult. I have many SUV and truck sounds, but none are quite like the actual H2, especially internal sounds, door slams, acceleration. Any insight would be great, or if someone out there has a Hummer or access to one, I would be interested in talking about a custom pack. Thanks all and hope everyone is well.

Best,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

There's relatively good INT and EXT coverage of an H2 in the Sound Ideas HD General Library. A quick search of our SFX library yields 120 recordings from them.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some vehicles with similar engine configs (6.0L 325 hp [242 kW] V8 (2003–07)
6.2L 393 hp [293 kW] V8 (2008–09)), you may want to investigate the following:

- Ford F350
- Ford Excursion
- GMC Sierra

That's if you're looking to closely approximate the actual sound. If your needs aren't as rigid and you just need it to sound "beefy" and cool, then start experimenting with all kinds of different diesels, from big rigs to actual Humvees to armored cars.